# O365 iOS Microsoft Graph SDK- How to get next page of one drive search results

Tags: ios, search, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am playing with [O365 iOS Microsoft Graph SDK](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-ios). I am searching one drive for 'xxx', When i use the nextRequest item to get next page of the search results i get following error

2017-05-30 16:24:30.413 O365-iOS-Microsoft-Graph-SDK[36063:3959258] Graph SDK ERROR : Error from data task : Error Domain=com.microsoft.graph.errors Code=400 "bad request" UserInfo={error= invalidRequest : Invalid query option, NSLocalizedDescription=bad request}
2017-05-30 16:24:30.414 O365-iOS-Microsoft-Graph-SDK[36063:3959258] Graph SDK ERROR : Caused by request  { URL: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/root/microsoft.graph.search(q='.xxx')?$skiptoken=MjAx(q=null) }

here is the code

```
MSGraphDriveItemSearchRequest *itemSearchRequest = [[[[[self.graphClient me] drive] items:@"root"] searchWithQ:@".xxx"] request];
[itemSearchRequest executeWithCompletion:
 ^(MSCollection *response, MSGraphDriveItemSearchRequest *nextRequest, NSError *error) {
     if(!error) {
         [nextRequest executeWithCompletion:
         ^(MSCollection *response2, MSGraphDriveItemSearchRequest *nextRequest2, NSError *error2) {
             if(!error2) {

             }
         }];
     }
 }];
```

If i use graph explorer and use (https: //graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/root/microsoft.graph.search(q='.xxx')?$skiptoken=MjAx) as query, i get the 'next' page of search results, i wonder why it is not working with the code i pasted.

Comment: This sounds like a bug within the SDK. I'd suggest posting this as an Issue in the [SDK's GitHub repo](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-ios/issues)